# RewriteCond of htaccess is not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Below is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php/api/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^lib/(.*) lib/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^applications/(.*) applications/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/index.php /lib/vt-index.php?clientid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^?]*) /lib/vt/$2?clientid=$1 [QSA]
```

I have some issues:

1. lib and applications are folders, but `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` has no effect, I have to write condition for lib and application separately.
2. The main issue is my api calls are not giving me result. I am calling my api as `www.myweb.com/api/User/xyz%40gmail.com` which is redirecting to `www.myweb.com/api/index.php/api/User/xyz%40gmail.com`, which is right. But calls to this are blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `RewriteCond` only gets applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`. Conditions aren't set globally nor get applied to more than one rule. You'll either need to repeat the condition for each rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php/api/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^lib/(.*) lib/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^applications/(.*) applications/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/index.php /lib/vt-index.php?clientid=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^?]*) /lib/vt/$2?clientid=$1 [QSA]
```

Or you can negate the condition and let it pass through first:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php/api/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^lib/(.*) lib/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^applications/(.*) applications/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/index.php /lib/vt-index.php?clientid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^?]*) /lib/vt/$2?clientid=$1 [QSA]
```

This way, the opposite of your conditions get applied to a rule that simply says "do nothing, and no more rewriting". In order for any of the bottom 5 rules to get applied, the conditions at the top would *not have been met*.